# testrpc install on OSX with node-gyp error

Tags: solidity, testrpc

Trying to get testrpc running locally, has anyone run into this?

```
$ sudo npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
npm WARN lifecycle scrypt@6.0.3~preinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) scrypt@6.0.3 node node-scrypt-preinstall.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/scrypt-ffbb6685
/usr/local/bin/testrpc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/bin/testrpc

> scrypt@6.0.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/copied_files.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/copied_files.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
```

...

```
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the scrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs scrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls scrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Maurice/Eth/solidity/testrpc/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Relevant error "ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5" - Google https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ld%3A%20library%20not%20found%20for%20%2Dlgcc_s.10.5#hl=en&q=%22ld:+library+not+found+for+-lgcc_s.10.5%22&* - Answer https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40653

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by manually installing crypt library using the following command:

`brew install libgcrypt`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error on Ubuntu 16.04. This was because node version ~4.x.x was installed the as opposed to the required 6.x.x (default under `sudo-apt-get install nodejs`).

After reading [this](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1060#issuecomment-334992869), I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786279) to install v6 of node and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by running `xcode-select --install` in terminal.

Found the solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381.).